# Short Exact Sequence from Single Arrow in Abelian Category

Tags: homological-algebra, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

Work in an abelian category. I'm aware that given an exact sequence, one can [break it into short exact sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Facts) like so:

[image]

I was wondering whether it was possible to do derive one of these short exact sequences from a single morphism alone: specifically, **given just a single arrow $A \xrightarrow f B$, is it true that one can obtain a sequence
$$ 0 \to \ker f \to A \to \operatorname{img} f \to 0 $$
which is short exact?** I think this should be true (for example it's true in $\mathsf{Grp}$ and $\mathsf{Vect}_k$, among other categories) but I can't find a reference confirming this somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course this is true, and in fact, this is said in the wikipedia article you linked !

Indeed, in the exact sequence involving the $A_i$'s, the $C_i$ do have a concrete description : $C_i=\ker(A_i\rightarrow A_{i+1})=\operatorname{im}(A_{i-1}\rightarrow A_i)$.

So if you just consider $f:A_1\rightarrow A_2$, you get a short exact sequence
$$ 0\longrightarrow \ker f\longrightarrow A_1\longrightarrow \operatorname{im} f\longrightarrow 0$$

You even have a second one :
$$ 0\longrightarrow \operatorname{im}f\longrightarrow A_2\longrightarrow\operatorname{coker} f\longrightarrow 0$$

Comment: Great, thanks. Mainly, I wanted to make sure that this didn't somehow depend on any adjacent terms in the short exact sequence (i.e. I wanted it to come from only one arrow), but I couldn't find a reference for it outside this context anywhere.

Comment: @EChen Ok, by the way, you can prove directly that those short sequences are exact. The second is true almost by definition, the first is almost an immediate consequence of the axiom of abelian categories that $\operatorname{coim}f\simeq\operatorname{im}f$.